# Displaying sub-categories in sidebar when parent category selected

Tags: php, wordpress

What I'm trying to achieve in WP 3.1.x using the `wp_nav_menu` function, is to have a menu such as:

```
-- Category 1
-- Category 2
-- Category 3
-- Category 4
-- Category 5
-- Category 6
```

But when you're on 'Category 2' it displays as:

```
-- Category 1
-- Category 2
  -- Sub Category 1
  -- Sub Category 2
  -- Sub Category 3
-- Category 3
-- Category 4
-- Category 5
-- Category 6
```

PS. I'm not looking for CSS hide/show functionality, that can be achieved easily.

PPS. Is a possible solution for this extending the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class?

Comment: If you're using `wp_nav_menu`, you should have the whole nav prebuilt in *Admin -> Appearance -> Menus*. Are you building the nav menu on the fly?

Comment: I don't want the sub-categories displaying by default, only when the user is on the applicable category

Comment: Just to be clear, an unacceptable solution would be one that prints out all sub categories for all categories and the non-current category sub-categories are hidden? If that doesn't work, I don't think you can accomplish this with `wp_nav_menu`. Rather, I think you'd have to write a function that first looks to see what the parent is and then generates the menu and only displays the sub categories for the current parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you subclass the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class you can override the `display_element` function and conditionally remove an item's children before they are looped through.

```
if (!$element->current && !$element->current_item_ancestor && isset( $children_elements[$id])) {
   unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
}
```

This would remove the children of any item that is not current, so you would need to check the item's type if you just want to do this for categories. The complete walker would look something like this: https://gist.github.com/954627

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I wasn't aware of the display_element method in the Walker class. I'll go through it a bit later and let you know the results

Comment: Genius! Worked well enough for me to modify to get it how I want it! Thanks.